# One variable in kg and grams. another indicates which unit; how can I get new variable in kg?

Tags: stata

In Stata `quantity` has inputs in both kg and grams. while `unit =1` indicates kg and `unit=2` indicates grams. How can I `generate` a new variable `quantity_kg` which converts all gram values into kg?

```
My existing dataset-

clear
input double(hhid quantity unit unit_price)
  1   24 1   .
  1    4 1   .
  1  350 2  50
  1  550 2  90
  1    2 1  65
  1  3.5 1  85
  1    1 1  20
  1    4 1  25
  1    2 1   .
  2    1 1  30
  2    2 1  15
  2    1 1  20
  2  250 2  10
  2    2 1  20
  2  400 2  10
  2  100 2  60
  2    1 1  20
```

My expected dataset

```
input double(hhid quantity unit unit_price quantity_kg)
  1   24 1   .  24
  1    4 1   .  4
  1  350 2  50 .35
  1  550 2  90 .55
  1    2 1  65  2
  1  3.5 1  85  3.5
  1    1 1  20  1
  1    4 1  25  4
  1    2 1   .  2
  2    1 1  30  1
  2    2 1  15  2
  2    1 1  20  1
  2  250 2  10 .25
  2    2 1  20  2
  2  400 2  10 .40
  2  100 2  60 .10
  2    1 1  20 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// unit 1 means kg, unit 2 means g, and 1000 g = 1 kg
generate quantity_kg = cond(unit == 1, quantity, cond(unit == 2, quantity/1000, .))
```

Your example doesn't have any missing values on `unit`, but it does no harm to imagine that they might occur.

Providing a comment by way of explanation could be anywhere between redundant and essential for third parties.

Answer (score 2):

The code below does what you want.

This looks like household data where one typically has to do a lot of unit conversions. They are also a common source of error so I have included the best practice of defining conversion rates and unit codes in locals. If you define this at one place, then you can reuse these locals in multiple places where you convert units. It is easy to spot typos in the rows with `replace` as you would notice if one row said `kilo_rate` but then `gram_unit`. In this simple example it might be overkill, but if you have many units and rates, then this is a neat way to avoid errors.

```
clear
input double(hhid quantity unit unit_price)
  1   24 1   .
  1    4 1   .
  1  350 2  50
  1  550 2  90
  1    2 1  65
  1  3.5 1  85
  1    1 1  20
  1    4 1  25
  1    2 1   .
  2    1 1  30
  2    2 1  15
  2    1 1  20
  2  250 2  10
  2    2 1  20
  2  400 2  10
  2  100 2  60
  2    1 1  20
 end

*Define conversion rates and unit codes
local kilo_rate = 1
local kilo_unit = 1
local gram_rate = 0.001
local gram_unit = 2

*Create the standardized variable
gen     quantity_kg = .
replace quantity_kg = quantity * `kilo_rate' if unit == `kilo_unit'
replace quantity_kg = quantity * `gram_rate' if unit == `gram_unit'
```

Comment: This style of defining constants early in a block is widely considered good for mainstream languages. Whether it's good for Stata beginners is perhaps a different question.  Clearly it is not essential to use local macros for this purpose.

Comment: While I agree in the facts, I think style and best practices are not emphasized enough in the Stata community - which leads to the Stata community writing more error prone code than other communities.

Comment: The task is to divide some numbers by 1000 and to leave others as they are. I see that as requiring about two lines, one a comment by all means. I would be interested to see your Stata scripts (and Stata commands if you've written any).